# How to centralize child DIVS containing UL?

Tags: css, html, footer

I am building a footer but I am having trouble getting the 4 divs which contain links to various pages to centralize. On dreamweaver it behaves correctly, but as soon as I upload it or test it on JSFIDDLE its decentralized.

Ideally I want it to look like this, with each of the divs 'centered' in the footer:

```
        Random information above the divs below (displayed center of footer)

                 Product      Company      Etc....        Contact

                 link         link

                 link         link
```

And so on.

I have a demo here which has the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/NkFe9/3/

Here is some of the CSS:

```
/*global footer settings*/
#footer {
color: #C9C9C9;
min-width: 1500px;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
list-style: none;
height: 450px;

background-image:url(../img/index/footer/pixelpatterns.png);
background-repeat:repeat;

}


#insidefooter {
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

/*settings for social media buttons*/
#insidefootertermsplusbuttons li {
display: inline;
color: #C9C9C9;

}

 #insidefooterone h5, #insidefootertwo h5, #insidefooterthree h5, #insidefooterfour h5 {
text-align:left;
margin-bottom: 0;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

 #insidefooterone ul, #insidefootertwo ul, #insidefooterthree ul, #insidefooterfour ul{
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 0;
color: #C9C9C9;
}

#insidefooterone li, #insidefootertwo li, #insidefooterthree li, #insidefooterfour li {
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 0;
color: #C9C9C9;
}

#disclaimer {

margin-top: 20px;
font-size: 9px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

#disclaimer p {
text-align:center;
color: #C9C9C9;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just a quick comment, do not trust Dreamweaver's design view. **Ever**.

Comment: I believe you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NkFe9/3/

Comment: @Ruddy lesson learnt the hard way!

Comment: @ben_dchost When I started web development I did the exact same thing!

Comment: @Aditzu that's how I want the heading and the div to line up. But how do I get the divs to be central in the footer, not to the left?

Comment: @Ruddy it's really deceiving! Is the preview in browser ok to use for feedback?

Comment: @ben_dchost Yes, always look at it in a browser.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NkFe9/4/  I added two wrappers to do the trick. I hope this is want you want ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `padding:0` to `ul`

```
#insidefooterone ul, #insidefootertwo ul, #insidefooterthree ul, #insidefooterfour ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #C9C9C9;
    padding:0
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NkFe9/2/)**

And dont judge the output based on dreamweaver Design view. Always prefer to check in browser.

---

You need to use `margin:0 auto` to make the div center aligned. `margin:0 auto` wont make any difference with `float:left`. So you need to eliminate float: left from the parent div.

And try adding a parent div to the `ul` links so that it is easy to align it.
**[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/suraqoja/3/)**

Comment: thank you for your reply. That's sorted one of the issues, but how do I centralize the divs in the footer though?

Comment: There are actually quite more modification in your code. Have updated the answe with the new DEMO hope you get to identify the changes.